# .NET MAUI Shell.SearchHandler null

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

I try to add a SearchHandler to my shell like this:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage ...>
<Shell.SearchHandler SearchBoxVisibility="Visible" Placeholder="Suche...">

    <controls:AnimalSearchHandler Placeholder="Enter search term"
                                  ShowsResults="true"
                                  DisplayMemberName="Name">
    </controls:AnimalSearchHandler>
</Shell.SearchHandler>
```

...

Handler:

```
public class AnimalSearchHandler : SearchHandler
{
    protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        base.OnQueryChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "Test" };

    }

    protected override async void OnItemSelected(object item)
    {
        base.OnItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Everytime I start the app in the emulator and the page gets loaded I get this error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I also tried to add a List with Animal objects and a Property Name. Same result.

Comment: With the above code snippet alone, we can't tell what went wrong. Which line of code reported this error? If it is convinient for you,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi, that's the thing. There is no line of code reported. I guess it's an Android exception. The app starts, when it hits the view I only find the error message in the output window. I'll try to setup a basic demo and report it